# Remove extraneous items from Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I am running Windows 10.

Currently, I have my Windows Explorer like this:
[image: Current State]

I would like to make it so that my explorer would only show folders that I pin to it.  For instance:
[image: Target State]

There are certainly methods available to remove individual folders (e.g. [OneDrive](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b18615f-2e81-46cb-bd11-d2035b7b015c/remove-onedrive-from-the-explorer-side-panel-in-windows-10?forum=WinPreview2014Setup)) but are there any overall ways to everything from the Navigation Bar that I did not explicitly add?

Comment: I don't believe you can since it doesn't seem to be possible in windows 7, i've searched for this sometime ago and couldn't find anything that could change this behaviour from explorer, hopefully someone has a solution?

Comment: Hey - check out the solution I found - although I did figure out how to do most of what I wanted using native registry changes, I have fallen in love with QTTabBar which lets you totally customize what you have on the sidebar (or top bar or bottom bar or wherever you want click links or tools).

Answer (score 2):

After spending a bit of time on this, I finally came up with a solution that I am really happy with.

First off, we can come to a solution using the native Explorer by following the following guides:

- [Remove Extra Folders from My Computer in Windows 10](http://www.askvg.com/tip-remove-6-extra-folders-from-windows-10-explorer-this-pc/)
- [Remove Icons from Explorer Navigation in Windows 10](http://www.askvg.com/windows-10-tip-remove-onedrive-quick-access-homegroup-and-network-icons-from-navigation-pane-of-this-pc/)

This site is really amazing and there are definitely some tips that I am using. However, I came up with a much better solution, which has left my new Explorer looking like this:

[image: New Explorer]

I used the [QTTabBar](http://qttabbar.sourceforge.net/) extension in order to make this work with [Snipicon Icons](https://www.iconfinder.com/iconsets/snipicons). This is highly customizable and allows you to assign hotkeys, create a tabbed explorer, etc. It creates an entirely new experience.

While you are at it, I suggest that you also check out [Search Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) (for an amazing yet light search utility that is highly customizable and can search/index networked drives) and [T-Clock Redux](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock/releases/tag/v2.3.2%23151-beta) (which allows you to have a Taskbar with small icons yet display more information on the clock as well as display a more informative/powerful calendar for quick reference).

Comment: Thanks, i'll try those out, been searching some look good.

Comment: I did this several times now. It removes these folders for a short time only. It isn't permanently.

Comment: Try QTTabBar - it lets you create a custom sidebar that stays permanently!